# Passing data-id to bootstrap modal WITHOUT jquery

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I've seen many questions like this with the exact same solution to use Jquery. But I don't want to use Jquery on my Reactjs just to passing id to modal.

Here's my code :

```html
<!-- trigger to pop up modal -->
<button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#educationModalCenter"
          data-id={education._id} <!-- Here im trying to pass the ID -->
        >
          &times;
        </button>

<!-- Modals -->
<div
        className="modal fade"
        id="educationModalCenter"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5
                className="modal-title font-weight-bold"
                id="exampleModalLongTitle"
              >
                Delete Education
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Are you sure to delete this education? This cannot be undone.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => onClickDelete(education._id, pid)}
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Sure
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Every time button 'Sure' was clicked, it would take the first modal instead to delete. Is there any way to accomplish this WITHOUT using jquery?

thankyou for your help!

**UPDATE**

I've tried the solution below but it didn't work. Here's what I've done :

```
// set id
const [id, setId] = useState(null)

const ngesetID = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let dataId = e.target.dataset["id"] || e.target.getAttribute("data.id")
    console.log("ini ada kaga")
    console.log(dataId) // it changes to current ID

    setId(dataId)
  }

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ID terbaru")
    console.log(id) // Just to make sure and it really changed
  }, [id])
```

```html
<!-- trigger to pop up modal -->
<button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#educationModalCenter"
          data-id={education._id} <!-- Here im trying to pass the ID -->
          onClick={e => ngesetID(e)}
        >
          &times;
        </button>
```

But every time I hit the button from pop-up modal, it always pointing to the first modal.

```
<button
       type="button"
       className="btn btn-primary"
       // onClick={() => onClickDelete(education._id, pid)}
       onClick={e => cobaDoang(e, id)} // the 'id' revert back to the first ID modal
       data-dismiss="modal"
    >
     Sure
</button>
```

I'm not sure what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in the code you listed. Where is the code you are wanting to replace?

Comment: Yes because that was what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to get the ID without jquery, this is the solution with jQuery : `$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
     // As pointed out in comments, 
     // it is unnecessary to have to manually call the modal.
     // $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use jQuery inside a ReactJS project since it is a Javascript framework on it's own.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can use state in ReactJS which will update the DOM when state changes.

I would suggest to use Redux for a heavily state used project, for a lightweight state usage you can consider using Hooks.

Comment: No sir i don't use jQuery, and also i used redux. i'm trying to passing id modals WITHOUT jquery and that's why i asked this question.

Comment: Since you have redux integerated, then I would suggest to have a variable initiated inside store. This variable will be displayed in the model so when this variable is updated it will be reflected in the modal accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable like `selectedId`, and use it on the `<button>` and in the modal.

```html
selectedId = '';
...
<button onClick={() => {selectedId = education._id}}>
...
<button onClick={() => onClickDelete(selectedId, pid)}>
...
```

In your snippet:

```html
<!-- trigger to pop up modal -->
<button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#educationModalCenter"
          onClick={() => {selectedId = education._id}}
        >
          &times;
        </button>

<!-- Modals -->
<div
        className="modal fade"
        id="educationModalCenter"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5
                className="modal-title font-weight-bold"
                id="exampleModalLongTitle"
              >
                Delete Education
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Are you sure to delete this education? This cannot be undone.
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => onClickDelete(selectedId, pid)}
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Sure
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but it still pointing to the first modal. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: yes, I had multiple modals and every time I clicked the button it always gets the first ID modal. I tried useEffect and simple const just like your solution but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get the attr and store it in a state and use it wherever you want.



<button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#educationModalCenter"
          data-id={education._id} 
          onClick={this.openModel}
        />

openModel =(event)=>{
  let dataId = event.target.dataset['id'] or event.target.getAttribute("data.id");
  this.setState({dataId : dataId})
}
```

Comment: I thought this should work, but every time I hit the "sure" button from pop-up modal, it always reverts back to the first modal ID.

Comment: add attr to the sure button whilst modal open. I think your sure btn's attr is not updating.

Comment: have you seen my update? what should I do from there?

Comment: const ngesetID = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let dataId = e.target.dataset["id"] || e.target.getAttribute("data.id")
    console.log("ini ada kaga")
    console.log(dataId) // it changes to current ID
/// update state here and try
   this.setState({setId:dataId})
    setId(dataId)
  }

and set id state to null on close model